# Hello, i have info on 2 columns in excel and i need to get them together combined on one column

Tags: microsoft-excel

the data I have in excel that looks like this:

```
column a      column B   column c    column D

card type    card no        camp type      camp code
standard       20              CLASIC           1
CLASIC         30              standard         2
standard       40              CLASIC           3
CLASIC         50              standard         4
standard       60              CLASIC           5
CLASIC         70              CLASIC           6
```

And I need to look like this:

```
clasic  
    1;30
    3;30
    5;30
    6;30
    1;50
    3;50
    5;30
    6;30
standard    
    2;20
    4;20
    2;40
    4;40
```

Is there a way to do this in excel?

Comment: Why values 60 and 70 from column B are ignored in desired output?

Comment: Easiest way for that is with Power Query: https://exceloffthegrid.com/list-of-all-possible-combinations-using-power-query/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the results you show are only a partial given your data, you can do this using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

This code ASSUMES you will have matching entries in the `card type` and `camp type` tables. If you might not, you will need to provide the logic for how you want to handle that situation.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Change name in next line to match the actual table name in workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
 //Split into two tables (card and camp)
 //Then do a  Left Outer Join
    cardTbl = Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),2)),
    campTbl = Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.LastN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),2)),
    joined = Table.Join(campTbl,"camp type",cardTbl,"card type"),

   #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(joined,{"card type"}),

//Type as Text in order to combine the number columns
   #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{
        {"camp type", type text}, {"camp code", type text}, {"card no", type text}}),

//Group by "type"
//Then Sort by card no and camp code to get into the desired order
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"camp type"}, {
        {"Sort", each 
            Table.CombineColumns(
                    Table.Sort(_,{{"card no", 
                        Order.Ascending},{"camp code",Order.Ascending}}),
                    {"camp code","card no"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(";"), "Result"), Table.Type}
    }),

//Add the "type" to the top of each grouped/combined table
//Then expand the table column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Result", each 
        Table.FromList({[camp type]} & [Sort][Result], Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"Result"})),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"camp type", "Sort"}),
    
    #"Expanded Result" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Result", 
        {"Result"}, {"Result"})
in
    #"Expanded Result"
```

[image]